# Powershell: Autofilter based on a column value

Tags: excel, powershell, filter

I have seen several post on this but they all seem to use the same example so I am not sure how the code would differ from scenario to scenario:

Here is what I have:

```
$rng = $sheet.Cells.Item(1,7).EntireColumn #choose all columns from 1 to 7
    $rng.select | Out-Null # select this range
    $filterValue = @("TRUE") # create filter value, that is only choose when value matches "TRUE"
    $xlFilterValues = 7 # "found in MS documentation", copied not sure what this does
$objExcel.Selection.AutoFilter(7,$filterValue, $xlFilterValues) # here the first parameter value of 7 is the column I am trying to filter on


$rowMax = ($sheet.FilteredRange.Rows).count
 $colMax = ($sheet.FilteredRange.Columns).count
```

Although my script doesn't crash or anything, but looks like the filter isn't working. I have around thousand rows, where the filtering columns have values set to "TRUE", "FALSE" or *Blank*.

My expectation is:

will output 7 for $colMax and 40 (number of rows where column 7 has a value of "TRUE") for $rowMax.

However, I am getting `0` for `$rowMax`.

Comment: Why do you have `@("TRUE")` as the filter? Thats making the object a single item array

Comment: @trebleCode Yes I am aware of that, but it should still work right?

Comment: The autofiltering piece certainly works, where are you getting the rest of that code where you're using `FilteredRange.Rows`, etc.?

Comment: @trebleCode The whole code snippet is actually together. I have edited my post to reflect this. The code snippet before that opens the file and gets WSheet and those I believe are fine as I can see the rows. Do you want to anything specific?

Comment: For `$rowMax` you write `FilteredRange.Rows` (with a dot in between). For `$colMax` you use `FilteredRangeColumns` (no dot).

Comment: @Theo Thanks for pointing it out, it was a typo and I updated the post. However, now I get 0 for both $rowMax and $ColMax

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to open a tab delimited file and filter column M for a given value

```
$column = 13 # column M
$filename = "C:\temp\terminations.txt"
$criteria "Voluntary"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($filename)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$usedrange = $worksheet.UsedRange
$usedrange.EntireColumn.AutoFilter()
$usedrange.AutoFilter($column, $criteria)
```